# ggplot2: ribbon changes fill when ymin is greater than ymax

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have two time series data, and one goes higher than other for a certain period and then reverses the order in another period.  Can I use geom_ribbon to fill the gap between two lines and then use different color (e.g. gray if `ts2 > ts1` and pink if `ts2 < ts1`)?

it appears to me that ggplot seems doing implicitly like `aes(ymin=pmin(ymin,ymax), ymax=pmax(ymin,ymax))`, doesn't care which of two are actually greater.

Comment: I think adding a column indicating which one is greater and setting a colour scale on that variable might help.

Comment: You're much more likely to get folks to look at this question if you create a small, [reproducible](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/324364) example that we can run the illustrates what you're attempting.